# _GNU_SOURCE macro and epoll_wait behaviour

Tags: c, pthreads, signals, posix, epoll

I work on an app with several threads. One of them is used for epoll. This app also catches `SIGINT` signal and performs some finalization. Everything works ideally untill I set `_GNU_SOURCE` macros. This makes the program to stuck on the line:

```
int n = epoll_wait(epfd, events, N, -1);
```

So, setting `_GNU_SOURCE` prevents all (`recv` too) waiting calls from breaking on `SIGINT`. Why is it so? What is a workaround?

In particular I want to use `sched_setaffinity`. This needs `CPU_SET` which is available only with `_GNU_SOURCE`.

**UPDATE**

How I catch `SIGINT`:

```
static volatile int running = 1;
static void int_handler(int i) {
      running = 0;
}
```

then in `main`:

```
signal(SIGINT, int_handler);
```

Comment: How do you "catch the `SIGINT` signal"?

Comment: @KerrekSB , I've updated the question

Comment: If you use [`sigaction`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) (with `sa_flags` zeroed out) instead of `signal`, do things work?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, yes, this helps! Could you explain the difference?

Comment: I'll write an answer. Short version: _GNU_SOURCE gets you the BSD version of lots of things, include BSD "safe signals" if you use `signal`. `sigaction`, OTOH, lets you specify, with a flag, whether or not to restart system calls.

Comment: It's UB to call `signal` in a multithreaded program.

Comment: @KerrekSB,  is it  the same UB for `sigaction`?

Comment: @Leonidas: No, `sigaction` is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On GNU/Linux, most of the non-kernel header files in `/usr/include` are provided by the same packages that provide glibc. When glibc provides several implementations of a function, you can use [feature_test_macros](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html) such as `_GNU_SOURCE` to choose among the various implementations.

When you define `_GNU_SOURCE`, it also defines `_BSD_SOURCE` and, on newer versions of glibc, `_DEFAULT_SOURCE`. When these macros are defined, the header files will arrange to give you BSD versions of some functions. [signal](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html) is one of those functions.

Under various flavors of UNIX, `signal` does slightly different things. The difference that you encountered: what happens to certain "slow" system calls when they get interrupted when a signal is sent. On V7 and [System III](http://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=SysIII/usr/src/man/man2/signal.2) (and System V), an `EINTR` error would be returned from the system call after the handler returns. On [4.2BSD](http://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=4.2BSD/usr/man/man3/signal.3c), the system calls would be restarted.

If you use POSIX-standard [sigaction](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) instead of `signal`, you can choose whether system calls are restartable or not by setting or clearing the `SA_RESTART` flag from `struct sigaction`'s `sa_flags`.

In glibc 2.19, the System V version of `signal` winds up calling `sigaction` with flags `SA_RESTORER|SA_INTERRUPT|SA_NODEFER|SA_RESETHAND`, and the BSD version calls `sigaction` with flags `SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART`.

Another reason to use `sigaction`: as @KerrekSB points out, using `signal` in a multithreaded application has unspecified behavior.